# How fix the maven error: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName whean

Tags: java, maven

I try execute `mvn package` for my project, but always get the error.

In my *pom.xml* I add followed properties:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.resources.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
        <version>3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

And run `>mvn package -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but without success:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:99)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTJavaCompiler.getJavaWriter(JDTJavaCompiler.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:146)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1137)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1306)
    at com.reucon.maven.plugin.openfire.jspc.JspcMojo.compile(JspcMojo.java:279)
    at com.reucon.maven.plugin.openfire.jspc.JspcMojo.execute(JspcMojo.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Error throws this code:

```
public OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    super(out);
    if (charsetName == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("charsetName");
    se = StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(out, this, charsetName);
}
```

Help me please fix the error. I already lost 5 hours.

This question does not duplicate [it](http://What%20is%20a%20Null%20Pointer%20Exception,%20and%20how%20do%20I%20fix%20it?), because I query about maven.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Please fix the thema title. Thanks.

Comment: Also I tried add the <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> and also without success.

Comment: Also I try do this in other IDE(IntellJIDEA) and also fail.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta Very clearly not a duplicate, for once.

Comment: Try using the latest plugin version (3.3) and removing the duplicate encoding configuration from the plugin stanza (the project properties should be sufficient).

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta, I tried - nothing. I was able to build the project. For this I simple removed this   <packaging>my-plugin</packaging> from my pom.xml. I don't know how this related to this error, but now I can move forward.

Comment: @chrylis, I already tried - nothing.

Comment: Wait, you had some nonstandard `packaging` option set as well?

Comment: Ooopps..... there was `openfire-plugin`. I trying implement my own plugin, but so far without success.

Answer (score 0):

Put javaEncoding element in your pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.reucon.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-openfire-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <javaEncoding>UTF-8</javaEncoding>
    </configuration>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but problem is not actually now